# Are all radioisotopes equally dangerous?

Tags: biophysics, radioactivity, isotopes, medical-physics

I'm currently writing an issues investigation on the radioisotope plutonium-239. It's difficult to talk about the dangers of the radioisotope itself, since information on the internet is mixed. Apparently a very small intake of plutonium-239 is lethal, but practically it is unlikely that you will take in that much?

(Just to clarify, I have been considering potential danger to human health and the environment.)

It's confusing, and perhaps best that I bypass that argument. There are many alternative points I could write about, e.g. radiological weaponry, terrorism, unsustainability as a source of energy, nuclear warfare, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the toxicity of plutonium not physics

Comment: @JohnRennie Well, however toxic plutonium is, the reason for that is physical. Anyone answering would have to take that into consideration.

Comment: @JohnRennie See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72496/

Comment: Water is lethal, if you take too much of it... so is air. The question you ask is meaningless. One can work with the most toxic substances and not be in danger if one takes the necessary precautions and one can be killed by a poorly placed brick on a shelf. Just to be frank, the internet does not owe you and, even more so, people who have rather sinister motives any information about how dangerous substances have to be handled. If that is what you want to do for a living, earn the necessary credentials and join the people who have this knowledge.

Comment: @CuriousOne So, just to be clear, you don't know the answer?

Comment: Just to be clear, I know people who do and I will never ask them about the details of their work because that would put them, and me, at significant risk of government prosecution. To me that's a rational limit to what I have to know to feel good about myself. But, again, if you want to handle substances like Pu, join the club. The relevant job openings are not a secret and the government will pay for all the education you will need. Now, wether you will actually be happy working there...

Comment: @CuriousOne Not great to work at places like that?

Comment: Plutonium 239 is extremely rare on Earth but not that hard to make in an advanced laboratory.   The risk of exposure is likely only to happen to people who have access to labs, or access to shady people who deal in illegal fissionable material.    The risk is quite low to a normal person as we're not likely to run into Pt-239 in our lifetime.    Some was released in the Japan Nuclear accident as that was a plutonium plant.  Is your research on trace amounts of it, say from Fukushima or higher dosages?   I somehow doubt you want to write a safety manual on how to work with it.

Comment: @userLTK In all candour it's a high school assignment about the pros and cons of a chosen isotope. Completely above board.

Comment: It's poorly paid (compared to industry), you are under constant supervision, the department politics if often horrible, the paperwork is a killer and, worst of all, you will never make friends by trying to improve things. Been there, done that. :-) On the other hand... you get to do things that almost no other person on this planet gets to do. That's a very strong motivator, at least for a few years. If you can live with the downside, it could be a job for life. I can only suggest you try if for yourself... again. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne you say it's a meaningless question, yet you know people who can answer it?

Comment: @MadBanners homework questions are discouraged, unless the question is very specific and not just "give me an answer", but in a nutshell, it all starts with Uranium, which is rare but it can be mined.   U238 is most common, U235 much less so.    U238 is also less fissionable, but if U238 is bombarded by Neutrons and turned into Pt-239, it's then more useful for both power plants and bombs.     It's also potentially toxic.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-239#Hazards   Ideally, if there was more U235 we wouldn't need Pt239 but U235 is quite rare, so making Pt239 means more nukes.

Comment: The way you are talking about it it's meaningless. The way the people I know deal with it isn't. In any case, they won't tell me, even if I ask, and that's just as well. :-)

Comment: It's Pu-239, not Pt-239.  Pu-239 is made by bombarding non-fissile U-238 with neutrons and letting it decay into Pu-239.  Whether there is a lot of U-235 around or not, it takes a sophisticated isotope separation apparatus to concentrate enough U-235 to start a chain reaction, in a reactor or a bomb.  Pu-239 can be separated from U-238 by chemical means, which is a lot less complicated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pu 239 can be put in highly toxic radioactive isotopes.

As you know radio isotopes are mostly generated from the radioactive decay reactions and the heaviest material naturally occurring is U238.

Pu239 is mostly created in artificial nuclear reactions. The danger of the radio isotopes is measured by their half lives. Radio isotopes having longer half lives are treated as highly toxic and in this case half life is ~24000 years.

Short lived radio isotopes can be stored in a container and after sometime they are gone and that container pose no radioactive hazard. However long lived radio isotopes pose radiation hazard in case of leak from container. They can contaminate soil, water and air and results in radio toxicity.

Hence you may put radio-isotopes in low toxic (half life few days), mid toxic (half life few years) high toxic (half life much longer than human life) ranges.

Just imagine you put Pu239 in a Stainless Steel container, do you think that the container can hold that isotope for ~50000-100000 years and that's why it is highly toxic.

I hope it will help

EDIT:

you may find these video lectures very useful [[1]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bukjtmM2djU) [[2]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0tMs9EkktIY). If you are interested you can search more by keyword nuclear physics H. C. Verma NPTEL.

Regards

EDIT

@dmckee you are technically right. The toxicity also depends on the type of the radiation they emit (gamma, neutron, alpha or beta), among them neutron is most hazardous.

Any inert molecule is like radioactive particle with infinite decay time (which simply pose no health hazard). But I am talking about the really radioactive compounds, for example mildly radioactive $U^{238}$has ~$10^6$ disintegration per seconds per mole.

The toxicity I am talking about is not per person but for society. If one person dies with short lived isotope only he dies but if long lived isotope is released you may imagine what havoc may happen. It goes inside you and keep on emitting the high energy particles which will result in increased cancer or other deceases in whole area and this will last for thousands of years.

Yes it also depends on actual decay rates, for example thorium, which is even milder radioactive material, is a naturally occurring radio isotope in several places in the world, resulting in natural radioactivity far greater than the acceptable levels worldwide and people are still living there. Over thousands of years they apparently gain higher resistance to the radioactivity than others (I am not sure about it).

I hope I have clarified your objections (at least partially)

Comment: Just curious - what information on the internet is "mixed" about the toxicity of plutonium?  Have you found a site which encourages people to sprinkle a little Pu-239 on their corn flakes for breakfast?

Comment: @user16622 I think you are referring to someones comment over here. I was not in that discussion.

Comment: Although the half life of an isotope affects how you need to safely store or contain them, the radiation (strength and type) determines toxicity. You might have a very short half life isotope that is very lethal and another isotope (native uranium ore, for example) with a long half life that you could live on top of for years. How you define danger must include: dangerous to what? The environment or someone handling it?

Comment: @MarkRipley you are correct, two things are inversely proportional to each other. However when we talk of toxicity we usually talk about environmental toxicity. Ones who handle it are fairly trained and under monitoring. Suppose if a short lived isotope is leaked into a river then it can kill at the most few fish but it will have no effect on the ones who ate those fish, but a long lived isotope will contaminate whole river like slow poison and a huge number of living bodies may have increased risk of cancer. I hope it will help.

Comment: This *"Radio isotopes having longer half lives are treated as highly toxic and in this case half life is ~24000 years."* is simply wrong. The health risk of an isotope is related to it's specific activity (which is generally *higher* for short half-life materials) and the kind(s) and energy of the decays involved (radiation weighting factors). Very long halflife materials are a particular problem for containment and storage, but if you have the option of being locked in a room with a mole (or gram) of Pu-239 or a mole of Cs-137, you should pick the plutonium.

Comment: @dmckee please see the edited answer.